# Optimal SQL Query when ORDERing BY SUMs

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

*Just as a note, this question is an extension of [one of my previous questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676027/mysql-count-two-things-in-one-query) The parameters have changed, so I need a new answer.*

I have a MySQL Table that has four fields post_id(unique int), user_id(int), category(varchar), score(int).

My goal is to end up with two values, one being what percent of a user's posts are in "x" category.  The second is the sum of all the scores in that "x" category.  To do this I've assumed that I need to get three values from MySQL:

- SUM(`score`) GROUP BY `category`
- COUNT(`post_id`) GROUP BY `category`
- COUNT (`post_id`)

So that's a simple enough query to write.  Here's the difficult part: I need to get the top 50 users, ordered by some calculation like (percent + sum).  I guess I *could* write a query that does all the above math in a subquery/JOIN, and then just put an ORDER BY and LIMIT in the main query, but this seems inefficient.  I'm planning for 2million users, and each user could have 5000 posts.  If I did my query like that (I think) it would take **forever** to run through each of those records.

What is the most efficient way to run a query like this?  I've read about MySQL views which seem like a nice idea, but I've also read they have huge performance problems.  Is it worth it?

Or is it impossible?  Should I settle for running a CRON job a couple times a day, and just storing faux-realtime numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you already have a large user database and a lot of posts?

If you don't you could create a meta-table that keeps track of these sums and counts. These would be easy to update in real time when the user adds a post or a score. You wouldn't have to scan the DB every time you needed to recount posts and scores for the statistics because you'd already have them in a table. It would be easy to do the calculations on this table instead.

There's a little extra work in the beginning when you create the functions that add everything to the meta-table. But it would probably pay off in the long run.

Comment: No, I don't have very many users yet - I think a meta table would work.  I actually already have a sort of meta table that is storing some similar information, I think it would fit well with the rest of this data.